# Jquery Display block whose name is the result of the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display block whose name is the result of string variable
Can method .find() take a variables?

```js
var className;
$('.game--test').find('.assault--test').click(function(){
    className = '.assault-res';
    alert(className);
});
$('.game--test').find('.medic--test').click(function(){
    className = '.medic-res';
    alert(className);
});
$('.game--test').find('.gunner--test').click(function(){
    className = '.gunner-res';
    alert(className);
});
$('.game--test').find('.radioman--test').click(function(){
    className = '.radioman-res';
    alert(className);
});

$('.game--test2').find(className).show();
```

Comment: [jQuery find() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Any literal string value can be replaced with a variable containing that string.  Same with any other value.  There is nothing special with find that would restrict that.  `find()` is a javascript method on a jQuery object, which is a javascript object, and strings are strings.

Comment: However it should be noted in your snippet that the last command is executed synchronously, while the setting of the variable is done in event handlers, which will occur after the fact.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Find work with string variables okay.
I need something other solution for this task. Thank you c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version uses a data-target on the elements to determine which other element should be changed.  It also uses common classes to look up the like elements.  The up side to logic like this is that the markup describes your elements and if you ever changed how things relate, there is the potential that your javascript logic would not have to change.

Also changed the binding to a delegate cause, why not?  :)

```js
$('.game--test').on('click', '.test', function(e){
  $('.game--test2 .res')
    .removeClass('active')
    .filter('.'+ e.target.dataset.target)
    .addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.res {
  display: none;
}

.res.active {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="game--test">
  <button class="test" data-target="assault-res">Assault</button>
  <button class="test" data-target="medic-res">Medic</button>
  <button class="test" data-target="gunner-res">Gunner</button>
  <button class="test" data-target="radioman-res">Radioman</button>
</div>

<div class="game--test2">
  <div class="res assault-res">Assault Stuff</div>
  <div class="res medic-res">Medic Stuff</div>
  <div class="res gunner-res">Gunner Stuff</div>
  <div class="res radioman-res">Radioman Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey its really work. I replace buttons to div. And then i added some content ,its doesnt work. For example i added in "res assault-res" some tags like <img> and <a> and its does not to work

Comment: Your going to have to give me an example of the changed markup.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I found the solution of this. I just replace e.target.dataset.target to e.currentTarget.dataset.target and its work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/152379/

Comment: Thank you for help, again :)

Comment: Ahhh, good deal.  `this.dataset.target` would also net you the same result as well.  @AntonLevchuk

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to listen to event for a dynamic class name.

```
$('.game--test2').find('.'+classname).show();
// or
$('.game--test2 .' + classname).show();

you can also have one listener for any class that ends with `--test` and show a message depending on the element that was clicked

$('.game--test2 [class$=--test]').on('click', function(e) {
  alert($(event.target).attr('class') + ' was clicked');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I use solution from second answer^^